# Web crawler for detecting 404s on a local machine

Tags: web-development, hyperlink

I'm developing a website on my local machine on a VM backports of the production site. It's gotten rather large and cruft over the years, and one of our problems is link breakage.

I'd like to run a program that scans the site on my local machine and gives me a report of 404s. In addition to parse HTML links, this spider should be able to parse the CSS to test links in there. JS parsing would be a bonus.

I am running on Windows with the VM guest being Debian, so a Windows or Linux solution would be great.

From doing Google searches, I've found a number of websites that offer scanning services for public websites, but my local dev site is not public-facing. I need something that will run on my machine.

Comment: Related: [Website Link Checker for Linux](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/20764/185). Purpose was exactly the same (finding dead links on my sites), though I was (and am) "fixed to Linux", so it might not be an "exact duplicate" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - it runs under [python](http://www.python.org) and is cross platform and free or for something already put together there is also the python based [LinkChecker](http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/) - also gratis & opensource.

Link Checker is available for Windows, OS-X & Linux and comes with both command line and GUI interfaces.

[image] [image]