# Continuous website URL rechecker for Linux

Tags: linux, reporting, hyperlink, url

We regularly have broken links to and from our website; I'd like to operate a tool to report them, preferably on Ubuntu Linux.

The tool would be a link checker, crawling the site and reporting broken URLs with the URLs of the referring pages.

Our site is far too big to allow starting up a link checker application and waiting for it to finish.  So the actual crawling must be done in the background.

One approach is to run a command line [link checker for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20764/website-link-checker-for-linux) in an infinite loop.  It will crawl the whole site and generate a report at the end.  Once it's done, replace the previous report with the generated one and restart.

Drawbacks:

- When a URL breakage is detected, generating the report is usually hours or even days away.  By that time, the page in question may have been fixed.
- The same pages will be checked over and over, even when they haven't changed in years.
- Puts a pretty high load on the server.

Which link checker (as I said, preferably available for Ubuntu) fixes this?

Requirements:

- Maintains a database of crawled URLs, with last access time, status, last modification time, response time, MD5 hash of the page content.
- Crawls URLs in the database continually, spreading the load on the server.
- Revisits changing pages sooner than unchanging pages.
- Revisits fast pages sooner than slow pages.
- Reports each broken link with last access time, referring page, last time it wasn't broken if available.
- Updates its report continually.

Comment: "the report is usually hours or even days away" - how large is your site? 3h*50MBit/s=67 GB. Given a large website with 512 kB (without images, you do not download images, just headers), this is 130.000 pages that can be checked in 3 hours. If you talk about days, that's 2.1 million pages. Are your assumptions correct?

Comment: Last time I counted, the logs showed requests for 3690360 different URLs.

Comment: Ok, maybe you want to add a requirement for distributed execution then (like multiple processes in different locations worldwide)

Comment: No, that would be part of the chosen solution, not part of the problem, and I don't think it would help much, either. I'm trying to avoid putting too much load on the server.

Comment: Is it all served by one server?  Are those unique pages or does that count include API endpoints?  I am intrigued by this.

Comment: Served by one server. It's nontrivial to count 'unique pages' (there are web applications on the server) but I can strip query strings and recount.